# SO3 in wood ash

Tags: analytical-chemistry, elemental-analysis

I have seen several sources note that wood ash typically contains 3–4 % $\ce{SO3}$ by weight. My question is, why would ash have any $\ce{SO3}$? $\ce{SO3}$ boils at 45 °C, so it should have all boiled away by the time the wood turned to ash.

Some sources for wood ash composition:
[Source 1](https://digitalfire.com/4sight/material/pine_wood_ash_1119.html)
[Source 2](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51190303_Sodium_and_Potassium_Released_from_Burning_Particles_of_Brown_Coal_and_Pine_Wood_in_a_Laminar_Premixed_Methane_Flame_Using_Quantitative_Laser-Induced_Breakdown_Spectroscopy)
[Source 3](https://www.sintef.no/globalassets/project/cenbio/cenbio-final-conf/2017-03-14_bjarte_oye_cenbio_final_conference.pdf)

Comment: ;/ It's oxide percent value, there's no SO3 there, but its salts.

Comment: Salts such as CaSO3 and Na2SO3? Why not Na2SO4?

Comment: No, Na2SO4 etc. - it's treated as Na2O + SO3

Comment: Great, thank you. That really clears this up for me.

Comment: Wouldn't the bulk of S in wood burn off as SO2 gas ?

Comment: Probably not. https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jcersj1950/94/1091/94_1091_615/_article says that Na2SO4 decomposes at 1450c. Since this is above the melting point(884c), not to mention is hotter than normal wood fire, substantial S is likely to remain in the ash

Answer (score 2):

Generally, ashes of natural samples (e.g. plant material or soil) do not actually contain chemical compounds like $\ce{Na2O}$, $\ce{P2O5}$, $\ce{SO3}$, $\ce{K2O}$ etc. These are just the reference compounds for the calculation of results of the elemental analysis.